# Centralizers of elements in HNN extensions

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be a (countable) group, $H<G$ be a proper subgroup and $\theta:H\to G$ be an injective group homomorphism such that $\theta(H)\neq G$. Consider the HNN extension $\Gamma=<G,t \mid tHt^{-1}=\theta(H)>$

Similarly to [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/142949/centralizers-in-amalgamated-free-products), if $H$ and $\theta(H)$ are malnormal  in $\Gamma$, then the centralizer of a nontrivial element in $\Gamma$ is either infinite cyclic or it is in a conjugate of $G$.

Is it sufficient to assume that $H$ and $\theta(H)$ are malnormal in $G$ ? (eventually replacing cyclic by virtually cyclic ?)

Comment: One needs to be careful here. E.g., if $\theta:H \to H$ is the identity, then the $\Gamma$-centralizer of any $h \in H$ is the direct product $C_G(h) \times \langle t \rangle$. Also, if $\theta$ maps any $h \in H$ into $ghg^{-1}$ for some $g \in H$, then the centralizer of $t^{-1}g$ will not be cyclic either. The natural sufficient requirement for the desired property should be that $H^g \cap \theta(H)=\{1\}$ for all $g \in G$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. Actually, I realized that this is implicitly contained in the paper of Karrass and Solitar, namely if $H$ and $\theta(H)$ are malnormal in $G$ and $H^g\cap \theta(H)=1$, for all $g$, then the centralizer of a nontrivial element is as above. But is not clear what happens with the centralizer if a conjugate of $H$ touches $\theta(H)$.